# Why last array filled with first array without asking?

Tags: java, arrays

I try to hold some value in 1st array, then another value in 2nd array, I try to print 1st array and it returns 2nd array values. Any ideas why ?

this is main method to call program

```
public class testC
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        groupC trial = new groupC();
        trial.setCol(10, 10);
    }
}
```

this is class calls another class to get color and fill in array each new coordinate

```
public class groupC
{
    private color1 col = new color1();
    private int[] cola1 = new int[3];
    private int[] cola2 = new int[3];

    public groupC()
    {

    }

    public void setCol(int xIn, int yIn)
    {
        cola1 = col.getCol(xIn, yIn);
        System.out.println(cola1[0] + " " + cola1[1] + " " + cola1[2]);
        /* try next color depending on 1st */
        cola2 = col.getCol(xIn + 100, yIn + 100);
        System.out.println(cola2[0] + " " + cola2[1] + " " + cola2[2]);

        System.out.println("this is 1st color, but why now the same as 2nd  ?" + cola1[0] + " " + cola1[1] + " " + cola1[2]);
    }
}
```

this is class, which simply gets coordinate and return array of color values at that point

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;

public class color1
{
    int[] color = new int[3];

    public color1()
    {
    }

    public int[] getCol(int xIn, int yIn)
    {
        // accepts position of color, returns size 3 array of red green blue
        // integers
        try
        {
            Robot r = new Robot();
            Color x = r.getPixelColor(xIn, yIn);
            color[0] = x.getRed();
            color[1] = x.getGreen();
            color[2] = x.getBlue();
        }
        catch (AWTException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return color;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that the `color1` class you've shown is actually the `colorD` class your code is using.

Comment: Also, as a side note - Name your `Type`s with BlockCaseLikeThis, not camelCaseWordJoint. Semantics and makes your code more reusable :)

Comment: Yes there is mistake when i made the code shorter, colorD is color1 here, fixing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `color1` *reuses* a single array:

```
public class color1
{
    int[] color = new int[3]; // <== Creates one array for this color1 instance
    // ...
}
```

All that happens in `getCol` is that it gets filled in (again):

```
Color x = r.getPixelColor(xIn, yIn);
color[0] = x.getRed();   // <==== Nothing here is creating a new color array
color[1] = x.getGreen();
color[2] = x.getBlue();
```

If you want to use more than one array, you have to actually create more than one array. That would probably mean removing the `color` instance member entirely, and creating the array in `getCol`:

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;

```
public class color1
{
    public color1()
    {
    }

    public int[] getCol(int xIn, int yIn)
    {
        // accepts position of color, returns size 3 array of red green blue
        // integers
        int[] color = new int[3]; // Has to be here because of how you're (not) handling exceptions
        try
        {
            Robot r = new Robot();
            Color x = r.getPixelColor(xIn, yIn);
            color[0] = x.getRed();
            color[1] = x.getGreen();
            color[2] = x.getBlue();
        }
        catch (AWTException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only actually populating a single array - and overwriting it every time you call `getCol`. So the values of `cola1` and `cola2` end up referring to the same array, whereas you want them to refer to *different* arrays.

You should probably be creating a new array in `getCol`, declaring `color` as a local variable instead of a field:

```
// Note rename of method to be more descriptive
public int[] getColorComponents(int xIn, int yIn)
{
    int[] components = new int[3];
    // accepts position of color, returns size 3 array of red green blue
    // integers
    try
    {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        Color x = r.getPixelColor(xIn, yIn);
        components[0] = x.getRed();
        components[1] = x.getGreen();
        components[2] = x.getBlue();
    }
    catch (AWTException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return components;
}
```

(As an aside, "handling" exceptions by just catching them, printing a stack trace and then continuing as if nothing had gone wrong is almost never the right approach. Additionally, you should work on your naming - none of your class names describe their purpose, and all violate Java naming conventions.)

Comment: Thank you very much for constructive feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Array variables are references in Java, so if you assign an array variable to another one, and modify one of them, then the other also gets modified:

```
int[] a = new int[3];
int[] b;
b = a;
b[0] = 42;
System.out.println(a[0]);  //: 42
```

To fix it, add the following to the beginning of `getCol`:

```
color = new int[3];
```

Even better: make `color` a local variable of `getCol`:

```
int[] color = new int[3];
```